The dual of the Bergman space is the Bloch space
The Bergman space $\mathcal{A}^1$ is the space of holomorphic functions on the disk such that,
$$
\|f\|_{\mathcal{A}^1} = \int_{\mathbb{D}} | f(z)| \, dA(z) < \infty.
$$
I have seen in several books that the dual space of $\mathcal{A}^1$ is $(\mathcal{A}^1)^* = \mathcal{B}$, the space of holomorphic functions on the disk such that,
$$
\|f\|_{\mathcal{B}} = \sup_{z \in \mathbb{D}} (1-|z|^2)|f'(z)| < \infty,
$$
with the dual pairing,
$$
\langle f,g \rangle_1 = \lim_{r \to 1^-} \int_{\mathbb{D}} f(rz)\, \overline{g(z)} \, dA(z), \quad g \in \mathcal{B}, f \in \mathcal{A}^1.
$$
On the other, hand I have seen a definition where they just get rid off the limit and define it just for the polynomials and thay say they can extend it by density. In that case we have the dual pairing,
$$
\langle f,g \rangle_2 = \int_{\mathbb{D}} f(z)\, \overline{g(z)} \, dA(z), \quad g \in \mathcal{B}, f \in \mathcal{A}^1 \cap \mathit{Polynomials}.
$$
Questions

How is the density argument applied?

My try is, that if $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$ is not a polynomial you consider the partials sums $f_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k$. And define the dual pairing in that case as,
$$
 \langle f,g \rangle_2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle f_n,g \rangle_2.
$$
But how can I know that the limit exists? I have thought about proving it's a Cauchy sequence, but I don't know how to prove it.

Consider $f$ and $f_n$ as stated in the question. Now, we are going to show that the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle f_n,g \rangle_2, 
$$
exists; for which we introduce the following radial estimates of the Bloch functions.
From [1] we have that,
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |g(re^{i\theta})| \, d\theta = O \left( \left( \log \frac{1}{1-r}\right)^{1/2} \right), \quad \text{as } r \to 1,
$$
valid for $g \in \mathcal{B}$ the Bloch space. Therefore we have that,
$$
\left| \langle f_m,g \rangle_2 - \langle f_n,g \rangle_2 \right| =
 \left| \int_\mathbb{D} \sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k z^k \; \overline{g(z)} dA(z) \right| \leq 
\sum_{k=n+1}^m |a_k| \int_0^1 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}   \, r^k \, |g(re^{i\theta})| \, d\theta\, r \, dr.
$$
Now we can split this integral into 2 parts taking an $s$ sufficiently close to 1 and use the estimate that we know have,
$$
\left( \int_0^s + \int_s^1 \right) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \, r^k \, |g(re^{i\theta})| \, d\theta\, r \, dr \leq
2 \pi M \int_0^s  r^{k+1} \, dr  + 2 \pi C \int_s^1 r^{k+1} \left( \log \frac{1}{1-r}\right)^{1/2} dr.
$$
Now we can take the limit as $k \to \infty$ and both integrals are $0$ by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, for example. This implies that we can find $N$ sufficiently big such that for all $N<n<m$ the quantity $\left| \langle f_m,g \rangle_2 - \langle f_n,g \rangle_2 \right|$ is small as we want. This means
that our sequence is Cauchy and therefore convergent.
References
[1] Girela, D. (1992). A note on the radial growth of Bloch functions. Bull. Austral. Math. Soc., 45(1), 143–149.
